# Вращение камеры вокруг центра экрана

Tags: c++, opengl, матрицы, glm

Для создания матрицы вида я использую две матрицы: матрица вращения (`mRotation`) и матрица трансляции (`mTranslation`).
Я хочу сделать так чтобы вращение было вокруг центра экрана вместо [0, 0, 0] в мировом пространстве.
Код вращения:

```cpp
void Camera::rotate(float angleX, float angleY)
{
    transform.rotation.x += angleX;
    transform.rotation.y += angleY;
    const glm::vec3 center{mTranslation[3][0], mTranslation[3][1], 0.0f};
    glm::mat4 rot{1.0f};
    rot = glm::rotate(rot, transform.rotation.y, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    rot = glm::rotate(rot, transform.rotation.x, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    rot = glm::rotate(rot, transform.rotation.z, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    mRotation = glm::translate(center) * rot * glm::translate(-center);
    mView = mTranslation * mRotation;
    mViewInverse = glm::inverse(mView);
}
```

Кстати я пробовал менять местами переумножение матриц:

```cpp
 mRotation = glm::translate(-center) * rot * glm::translate(center);
```

Результат тот же

Паномирование:

```cpp
void Camera::pan(float x, float y)
{
    const float zoomAmount = std::abs(mTranslation[3][2]);
    glm::vec4 motion(x * zoomAmount, y * zoomAmount, 0.f, 0.f);
    mTranslation = glm::translate(glm::vec3(motion)) * mTranslation;
    updateViewMatrix();
}
```

В качестве центра вращения я использую данные из матрицы трансляции. По идее данные верны. Центр вращения изначально идёт в [0, 0, 0]. Далее я двигаю сцену, масштабирую и данные с центра трансляции изменяются в соответствии с паномированием и масштабированием.

Но у меня происходит какая-то ошибка. Если я паномирую, вращаю, паномирую и снова вращаю, то сцена куда-то сдвигается. Это как-то странно ведь в первых двух шагах(паномирование, затем вращение) ничего не сдвигается. Подскажите пожалуйста что не так? Такое ощущение что центр трансляции сбивается и становится [0, 0, 0]

Ошибка выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.: Кстати, если для вектора `center` я указываю статичные данные (к примеру, [1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f]), то трансляция как тут не сбивается

UPD: Кажется я понял в чём проблема. Я когда менял матрицу при вращении менял все углы. Но центр же изменился. И изменять поидее нужны только новые углы. Т.е. был центр в [0, 0], произошло вращение. Далее центр сместился, скажем вправо. И менять нужны только те изменения которые возникли при новом центре. Но я пока не знаю как это пофиксить. У меня получается какая-то аркбол камера.

```cpp
const glm::vec3 center = {mTranslation[3][0], mTranslation[3][1], 0.0f};
    glm::quat rotationQuat{{angleY, -angleX, 0.0f}};
    glm::quat reverseOrient = glm::conjugate(rotationQuat);
    glm::mat4 rotationChanges = glm::translate(-center) * mat4_cast(reverseOrient) * glm::translate(center);
    mRotation = mRotation * rotationChanges;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сложить 2 матрицы вращения?

UPD: Ещё раз погуглил похожие вопросы. Ничего так и не вышло. Попробовал упростить. Даже без изменения углов матрица сдвигается. При этом я заметил что если изначальная позиция находится в +Z (к примеру, когда изначально формируем матрицу через `glm::lookAt`), то сцена почти не сдвигается. А если в -Z, то происходит деформация.
Чтобы было почти минимальное искажение для +Z:

```cpp
mRotation = glm::translate(center) * rot * glm::translate(-center);
```

Для -Z:

```cpp
mRotation = glm::translate(center) * rot * glm::translate(center);
```

Я не очень понимаю как это связано. При этом если рассмотрим вариант с -Z, то результат будет идентичным:

```cpp
mRotation = glm::translate(center) * rot * glm::translate(-center);
```

```cpp
mRotation = glm::translate(center) * rot;
```

Почему ничего не меняется когда я обратно транслирую на pivot point?

Comment: Вместо метода проб и ошибок стоило бы разобраться, как работают матрицы...

Comment: Ваш код доступен в каком-нибудь репозитории?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy нет. Весь код слишком громоздкий в рамках рассмотрения этого маленького вопроса. Но большую часть кода для построения матриц камеры я взял отсюда. https://github.com/Twinklebear/arcball-cpp.  Основное отличие это - то что здесь суммируется каждое изменение (в результате аркбол камера). А у меня хранятся данные углов и вращение строится от identity матрицы. (Как я писал выше. Вверху полная функция вращения)

Comment: Я готов помочь, если будет небольшое приложение, которое можно собрать и попробовать самому.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy сделал на скорую руку. Тут проблема видна. Также. С +Z норм. С -Z трансляция сбивается. https://github.com/wusikijeronii/cameraIssue0120023. И если прям жизнено важно довести демку до нормального состояния дайте знать. Просто решил сейчас на это время не тратить. Главное же показать проблему ;)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy кстати у меня получилось достичь верного результата проверкой является ли `dir().z` больше 1 или нет. Но я не уверен насколько это корректно. Я даже кажется понимаю почему это происходит. Когда мы смотрим спереди то экранное лево - это мировое лево. Но когда мы смотрим сзади то все наоборот. У меня честно говоря такая же проблема и с углами. Нужна проверка в какую сторону повернута камера. Иначе он поворачивает не в ту сторону. Подскажите ещё пожалуйста есть ли более правильный способ это сделать. Может быть есть какой-нибудь алгоритм применения ориентации?

Comment: Ещё раз проверил. При фиксированном векторе сцена не дёргается, но если я выставляю данные из `mTranslation`, то сцена сдвигается вдаль. При этом такое поведение есть только если вращение не равно 0. Т.е. я, скажем, повернул сцену на 30 градусов. Есть идеи почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в неправильном порядке умножения матриц.
Было:

```cpp
mRotation = glm::translate(-center) * rot * glm::translate(center);
mView = mTranslation * mRotation;
```

Надо:

```cpp
mRotation = rot;
mView = glm::translate(-center) * mTranslation * mRotation * glm::translate(center);
```